# Can this javascript be reduced?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, refactoring, simplify

I was curious to see if anyone knew a of a way to reduce this javascript code:

```
var channels;
channels = [];

$('li.suggestions article').each(function() {
  return channels.push($(this).data('channel-id'));
});
```

It's really simple -- the snippet just initializes an array called "channels", iterates over some DOM elements and collects their "data-channel-id" attribute, adding it to that array.

It is something I do a lot and it would be great to have this snippet simplified further -- I'd accept a CoffeeScript answer too if there is a nice solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var channels = $('li.suggestions article').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('channel-id');
}).get();
```